# Tomcat Connection Pool's attribute setting

Tags: jdbc, connection, tomcat7, jndi, application-pool

My web application connect DB by Tomcat jdbc pool.

this is my Tomcat context.xml

```
<Resource
            factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
            name="jdbc/OracleDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            initialSize="70"
            maxActive="100"
            maxIdle="30"
            minIdle="10"
            maxWait="5000"
            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
            username="XXOO"
            password="XXOO"
            driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            validationQuery="SELECT 'OK'"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            numTestsPerEvictionRun="5"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXOO:testdb"/>
```

connection timeout will be happened 1min50sec

If I use JDBC to connect  DB,it would not happen.

So what's setting do I  lose or modify?

Comment: What is the meaning of your title?

Comment: sorry,I modified.